# gradle error flutter and dart:ui- in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-gradle-plugin

I have this error in vs code

```
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

when I write in the terminal flutter run
and when I do run without debugging I find this error
dart:ui...
even the start debugging does not work

How do I solve it?

Comment: Did you run a flutter doctor and check everything is fine ?

Comment: please share the stack trace of the error.

Comment: @mazenamr i have one issues its the visual studio and i don't use it